# Resources on Solar Neutrino Physics

Tags: soft-question, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, education, neutrinos

For a project I'm doing for an introductory Astrophysics course, I'm trying to understand the nuances of [solar neutrino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino) physics.

However, most of what is said while explaining neutrino oscillations whizzes past me, as I have no background in particle/nuclear physics. Can anyone please tell me what are the concepts I need to understand in order to quantitatively understand the physics of Solar Neutrinos? Book and paper recommendations would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article on [Solar neutrinos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_neutrino)?

Comment: Yes. I have also gone through most of the links/papers posted on SE on this topic. I mostly want to know a list of concepts I need to understand to make sense of Solar Neutrinos.

Comment: Er ... somehow I don't suppose that you are looking for someone to list the concepts as (1) what are neutrinos (2) how do they mix in free space and (3) how does matter affect the mixing, but that is the naive answer.

Comment: Solar neutrinos are way, way past "introductory astrophysics", unless you are taking it at the university undergraduate physics level? If you want to understand the problem, you would need to have, at least, a cursory understanding of the neutrino producing processes in the sun, neutrino detection techniques and neutrino oscillations. Maybe THE standard text on these issues is http://www.amazon.com/Neutrino-Astrophysics-John-N-Bahcall/dp/052137975X by neutrino astrophysics "founder" John Bahcall.